# No puedo conectar mi controlador con Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Tengo un blade que llama a una funcion .js, la cual bota un sweet alert de borrado de datos.

```
<form action="{{ route('eliminar_chofer',['cId'=>$conductor->cId]) }}" 
   class="d-inline form-eliminar" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}  {{ method_field('delete') }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn-action-tabla eliminar tooltipsC" 
      title="Eliminar este registro">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash text-danger"></i></button></form>
```

que llama a la peticion que tengo en eliminar.js mediante el formulario con el nombre `form_eliminar`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabla-data").on('submit', '.form-eliminar', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = $(this);
    swal({
        title: '¿ Esta seguro que desea eliminar el registro ?',
        text: "Esta acción no se puede deshacer!",
        icon: 'warning',
        buttons: {
            cancel: "Cancelar",
            confirm: "Aceptar"
        },
    }).then((value) => {
        if (value) {
            ajaxRequest(form);
        }
    });
  });

   function ajaxRequest(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if(respuesta.mensaje == "ok") {
                form.parents('tr').remove();
                Ypfb.notificaciones('El registro fue eliminado 
    correctamente', 'YPFB', 'success');
            } else{
                Ypfb.notificaciones('El registro no pudo ser eliminado, hay 
    recursos usandolo', 'YPFB', 'error');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
        }
      });
     }
  });
```

todo llega bien hasta que llega a la funcion `AjaxRequest`, la cual tendría que mandar a mi controlador, pero lastimosamente no le llega:

```
 public function eliminar(Request $request, $cId)
   {
    if($request->ajaxRequest()){
        if(Chofer::destroy($id)){
            return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'ok']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'ng']);
        }
      }   else {
        abort(404);
      }
   }
```

No sé cual es el error ¡ayudenme por favor!

Comment: yo he usado el jax para el c# pero en la parte de url solo tendrías que poner el nombre del método, pero he encontrado un video que creo que te puede ayudar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb0HGKKp2dc Espero que te ayude Saludos

Comment: Vamos por partes. Chequeaste que esté llamando correctamente a `ajaxRequest()`? Hacé un `console.log(form)` dentro de esa función para ver si la está llamando.

Answer (score 0):

1. Un error basico que nos pasa a todos alguna vez, tu funcion debe estar por fuera del evento ready

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tabla-data").on('submit', '.form-eliminar', function () {
       event.preventDefault();
       const form = $(this);
       swal({
           title: '¿ Esta seguro que desea eliminar el registro ?',
           text: "Esta acción no se puede deshacer!",
           icon: 'warning',
           buttons: {
               cancel: "Cancelar",
               confirm: "Aceptar"
           },
       }).then((value) => {
           if (value) {
               ajaxRequest(form);
           }
       });
     });

   });

   ```
    function ajaxRequest(form) {
   $.ajax({
       url: form.attr('action'),
       type: 'POST',
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function (respuesta) {
           if(respuesta.mensaje == "ok") {
               form.parents('tr').remove();
               Ypfb.notificaciones('El registro fue eliminado 
   correctamente', 'YPFB', 'success');
           } else{
               Ypfb.notificaciones('El registro no pudo ser eliminado, hay 
   recursos usandolo', 'YPFB', 'error');
           }
       },
       error: function() {
       }
     });
    }
   ```

Segundo si no te funciona especifica el tipo de respuesta, es decir json

```
$.ajax({
type:"Post",
dataType:"json",
data:{id:id},
```